# Top navigation is not coming properly - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

My App is iPhone only and it works great on iPhone device. It got rejected by Apple with below message:

> iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone
>   resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

When I run my app on iPad it's cutting part of the navigator at the top. Attached is the screen print.

Anyone got any clue how to fix it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you navigation bar is covered because its position is lower than the 20point reserved for the status bar. To check its position, click on the navigation item or bar, go to Size Inspector and under View, you will see the X & Y positions. Or you can set constraints for it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem long back but missed to update the solution here. I was getting this issue on iPad because it doesn't use status bar as like iPhone for iPhone app. So I did leave the status bar space at the top of the view controller. Also, this issue occurs only for standalone ViewController and if we use Navigation ViewController, issue is automatically resolved.